# How can I create a push notification that goes off after x number of seconds? (iPhone/iPad)

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've been looking around online trying to research how to set up a push notification to go off after x number of seconds or a set time. I haven't been able to find anything to help me out though. I've found numerous good tutorials like [this](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services), however they don't seem to state how to set up when the alerts will go off.

Also, please could someone tell me what would happen if the user had the app open when the alert is due to go off? Will it just be ignored or will it still be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using local notifications instead? You can schedule it to go off at a certain time without having to make the server round-trip

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much! I wasn't even aware of local notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You need a script to connect to Apple's push notification servers in order to send out push notifications. The push notifications will be sent whenever you tell Apple's server to send them. You can setup a cron job on your server to send out the push notifications at specific times/intervals. [Here is a PHP tutorial](http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/) that will teach you how to send out push notifications. Once you have the push notifications working, setting up the cron job should be easy.

If the app is open and receives a push notification the following method will be called on your UIApplication and you can decide how to react to the notification:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```